# Best substitute for endless loop in thread

Tags: java, swing, coding-style

I'm new to GUI development in Java so I ran into the following problem:

In my `Graphics2D`-drawn custom component I'm doing a blinking animation. For this purpose I made a Java Thread which is changing a variable and calling the repaint() method periodically.

I know that creating an endless loop is considered to be bad programming style so do you know a better substitute or even better way to do simple animations with `Graphics2D` without the need for a custom-made thread?

## Code

### Loop

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    blinkState = true;
                    FeldPanel.this.repaint();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    blinkState = false;
                    FeldPanel.this.repaint();
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

### Extract from `paintComponent`:

```
if (highlightedField != null && blinkState) {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(highlightedField.getX() * 33, highlightedField.getY() * 33, 33, 33);
    }
```

Comment: Use a swing [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). There should be plenty of examples on this site.

Comment: `"I know that creating an endless loop is considered to be bad programming style..."` -- I'm not sure that I'd make this generalization. Can you post a reference that backs this up?

Comment: Thanks a lot kiheru!

Comment: @Hovercraft My textbook advises me to never use endless loops and because I'm still a beginner I try to obey my book

Comment: Fair enough. A Timer I believe will use a loop similar to this in its own background code, but it does offer nice methods to help you control its functions in a cleaner way than in your current code.